# File download using PHP not working via HTTPS (works fine via HTTP)

Tags: php, https

I'am being stuck for about a day on a strange problem (at least for me).

I have many (usually PDF) files on the server's filesystem and I want to serve them to users through PHP file to make business logic easier (logging downloads, making the name of the file on users' filesystems nicer, ...)

PHP code:

```
// $ext = extension of the file; 
// $fullPath = full path of the file being downloaded on server's filesystem    

switch($ext) { 
  case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break;
  case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break;
  case "doc": $ctype="application/msword"; break;
  case "xls": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
  ...
  default: $ctype="application/octet-stream";
}

$fsize = filesize($fullPath);

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers
header("Content-Type: " . $ctype);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $targetName . "\";");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: " . $fsize);
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($fullPath);
```

**Important:** I use CloudFlare (free) so for HTTPS I use their SSL certificate (that works fine for everything else just fine)

**And how it behaves?**

- In case I call the script using HTTP everything works fine.
- When calling it using HTTPS it behaves strangely:

  - [ERROR] Safari (MacOS): the file is downloaded to the client's filesystem but browser doesn't finish the download,
  - [ERROR] Chrome 54 (MacOS): it looks like it even doesn't start,
  - [ERROR] Chrome 51 (Win7 Enterprise + SP1): it looks like it downloads the file but at the end it says "Network error" and file cannot be opened,
  - [OK] MSIE11 (Win7 Enterprise + SP1): works just fine
  - [OK] curl in Terminal (MacOS): it works just fine and the file is downloaded and can be opened in the correct form

**What I tried so far:**

- Various file sizes - same behaviour
- Two ISP (100Mbit optic fibre + 30/8Mbit Wireless) - same behaviour
- Setting Cloudflare to Development mode (so I should bypass the Cloudflare but SSL is still being used - so I think this could be the root cause of the problem) - no change in behaviour
- Added logging of certain "breakpoints" in the script - it runs even for HTTPS request as expected (no difference between HTTP and HTTPS request)
- search the web / StackOverflow but all answers should be already in the PHP script above (like "add Content-Disposition", "remove all white spaces") or try new "download" attribute for hyperlink HTML element (but it is still rather new and doesn't easily offer solution for "business needs")

**Try by yourself** (it is approx. 1,5MB file)

- HTTP: http://www.zatrolene-hry.cz/dialog/download-file?id_soubor=123
- HTTPS: https://www.zatrolene-hry.cz/dialog/download-file?id_soubor=123

Comment: The https-download works fine for me (PC, Firefox and Chrome). So maybe just a local problem with your client in combination with the ssl certificate? Can't see anything "wrong" with your code.

Comment: Thanks for giving me another "vector" to check. But on PC with Windows7 it behaves strangly again (updated the question itself) -> on Win7 Enterprise in Chrome 51 - error, in MSIE11 - works fine

Comment: If you are using file_get_contents() with HTTPs then it will not work correctly.

Comment: That is strange I think there is no use of file_get_contents() in the code. To stream the file content I use readfile() function. Mainly because it should be much more memory friendly :-)

Comment: HTTPS - download works fine on windows 10 Chrome.

Comment: @OndřejMysliveček I had the very same issue, and on my case I was able to fix it by putting a simple exit call at the end (`readfile($fullPath); exit;`).